# Completing the square in a Gaussian distribution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, probability-distributions, completing-the-square

Let the distribution $\displaystyle p(\theta | x) = L(\theta | x)p(\theta) = p_{1} = \exp[-\frac{1}{2} ((\frac{\theta - x}{\sigma})^{2} + (\frac{\theta - \mu_{0}}{\sigma_{0}})^{2})]$ where $L$ is the likelihood function for $\theta$

How can I get to distribution $p(\theta | x) = p(\theta) = p_2 = exp[\frac{-1}{2} \frac{(\theta - \mu_{1})^{2}}{\sigma_{1}^{2}}]$
via completing the square

with the help of $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sigma_{1}^{2}} = \frac{1}{\sigma} + \frac{1}{\sigma_{0}^{2}}$, $\displaystyle\frac{\mu_{1}}{\sigma_{1}^{2}} = \frac{x}{\sigma^{2}} + \frac{\mu_{0}}{\sigma_{0}^{2}}$

Terribly rusty wit these. Any help is appreciated. Hints are encouraged.

Edit: corrected typos

Comment: A random hint on formatting: you can use \left and \right in front of delimiters to make them scale up: (\frac{1^1}{2_2}) becomes $(\frac{1^1}{2_2})$, while \left(\frac{1^1}{2_2}\right) becomes $\left(\frac{1^1}{2_2}\right)$

Comment: Could you define your notation more clearly?

Comment: At $p_2$ the variable x is missing. This doesn't make sense. Don't waste our time by posting senseless questions.

Comment: @callculus42 $p_{2}$ doesn't require an $x$ - $p_{2}$ is a posterior distribution. Instead of $x$, $\theta$ is the random variable - corresponding to some distribution parameter that we are trying to sample. The reason why I did not made that explicit is because it'll end up being a distraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still think there is an error in your formula
$$
   \frac{1}{\sigma^2_1} = \frac{1}{\sigma^\color{red}{2}} 
   + \frac{1}{\sigma_0^2}.
$$

Assuming this is indeed an error, since we are given the formulae of $\sigma_1$, $\mu_1$, expanding gives
$$
    \frac{1}{\sigma_1^2} = \frac{1}{\sigma^2} + \frac{1}{\sigma^2_0}
    = \frac{\sigma^2 + \sigma_0^2}{\sigma^2 \sigma^2_0}
    \tag{1}
$$
and
$$
    \frac{\mu_1}{\sigma_1^2} = \frac{x}{\sigma^2} + \frac{\mu_0}{\sigma^2_0}
    = \frac{\mu_0 \sigma^2 + x\sigma_0^2}{\sigma^2 \sigma^2_0}
    \tag{2}.
$$

The trick here is that by assuming the new distribution is in $\theta$, we can discard any term not $\theta$-related and treat them as normalizaing constants.
So
$$
\begin{align*}
\left[ \frac{(\theta - x)^2}{\sigma^2} \right] + 
\left[ \frac{(\theta - \mu_0)^2}{\sigma_{0}^2} \right]
&= \frac{\sigma^2_0 (\theta^2 - 2x\theta + x^2) + \sigma^2 (\theta^2 - 2\mu_0 \theta + \mu_0^2)}{\sigma^2 \sigma_0^2} \\ 
&= \frac{\sigma^2 + \sigma^2 _0}{\sigma^2 \sigma_0^2} \theta^2 
- 2\theta \frac{x \sigma_0^2 + \mu_0 \sigma^2}{\sigma^2 \sigma_0^2} + C 
\\
&= \frac{\theta^2}{\sigma_1^2}- 2 \theta \frac{\mu_1}{\sigma_1^2} + C
\tag{From (1) and (2)} \\ 
&= \frac{\theta^2}{\sigma_1^2} - 2 \theta \frac{\mu_1}{\sigma_1^2} 
+ \color{blue}{\frac{\mu_1^2}{\sigma_1^2}}
- \color{blue}{\frac{\mu_1^2}{\sigma_1^2}} + C \\ 
&= \frac{(\theta - \mu_1)^2}{\sigma_1^2} + C',
\end{align*}
$$
where $C$, $C'$ are normalizing constants not depending on $\theta$. This gives you the desired Gaussian form.

Comment: Yes - the missing square for the posterior was an error on my part. Thank you. I was so focused on manipulating the posterior expression that I overlooked attempting to do the same for the identities involving the posterior precision and the weighted precision for the posterior.

Comment: I think a potentially easier way is to work with the characteristic functions instead of the densities. However I have forgotten how to do it.